# Change value attribute of checkbox base on checked value with knockout JS

Tags: checkbox, knockout.js, customization, computed-observable

I'm trying to  a checkbox and send the value YES or NO in my submitted form, base in if is checked or no but the value is not updated
here is my code:

```
self.checkbox = ko.observable("No");
    self.is_checked = ko.computed({
        read: function (data) {
            return false;
        },
        write: function (data, event) {  self.is_checked() ? self.checkbox('Yes'):  self.checkbox('No');}

    });
```

data-bind="checked: is_checked, checkedValue:checkbox"

any clues or links to read, please.

Answer (score 0):

Your computed `read` function should return `true` or `false` so the UI is updated by the `checked` binding, and you can remove `checkedValue` entirely (checkedValue usually only makes sense to use with radio elements).

```js
self.checkbox = ko.observable("No");
self.is_checked = ko.pureComputed({
  read: () => self.checkbox() === "Yes",
  write: (v) => self.checkbox(v ? "Yes" : "No")
})
```

```html
data-bind="checked: is_checked"
```